# how to apply type writer animation using CSS on multiple strings

Tags: css, animation, sass

i want to apply `type writer` animation on multiple strings, i see mostly developer did this in JS but i want to do this with just CSS, so far i have done for just 2 strings but not more than that. if i do for 3rd string , 3rd string overlaps.

[Code pen link](https://codepen.io/klodfrol/pen/xxbLmLd)

HTML CODE.

```
           <h1>I am Kirill 
             <div id="stmt1">Acquistion strategist</div>
             <div id="stmt2">Campaign executioner</div>
             <div id="stmt3">Semi-technical marketing lead</div>
           </h1>
```

CSS code

```
#stmt2
{
    margin-top:-40px;
}
#stmt1
{
    width: 25em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: frag1type 10s steps(50, end) 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes frag1type{

        from { width: 0; opacity:1; }
        37%{width:25em;opacity:1; }
        49%{width:0;opacity:1; }
        100%{width:0;opacity:1; }
}

#stmt2
{
        opacity: 0;
        width: 25em;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        animation: frag2type 10s steps(50, end) 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes frag2type{

        from { width: 0; opacity:1; }
        37%{width:25em;opacity:1; }
        49%{width:0;opacity:1; }
        100%{width:0;opacity:1; }
    }

#stmt3
{
    margin-top: -40px;
}
#stmt3
{
        opacity: 0;
        width: 25em;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        animation: frag3type 10s steps(50, end) 7s infinite;
}
@keyframes frag3type{

        from { width:0; opacity:1; }
        37%{width:25em; opacity:1; }
        49%{width:0; opacity:1; }
        100%{width:0; opacity:1; }
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is in your timing. increase `10s` will  be fix it i think

Comment: @ttrasn no it doesnt i tried

Answer (score 0):

increase timing to `15s` and increase width in animation on `10%` and decrease on `25%`

```
animation: frag1type 15s steps(50, end) 0s infinite;
animation: frag2type 15s steps(50, end) 5s infinite;
animation: frag3type 15s steps(50, end) 10s infinite;

@keyframes frag1type{

        from { width: 0; opacity:1; }
        10%{width:25em;opacity:1; }
        25%{width:0;opacity:1; }
        100%{width:0;opacity:1; }
}
@keyframes frag2type{

        from { width: 0; opacity:1; }
        10%{width:25em;opacity:1; }
        25%{width:0;opacity:1; }
        100%{width:0;opacity:1; }
}
@keyframes frag3type{

        from { width: 0; opacity:1; }
        10%{width:25em;opacity:1; }
        25%{width:0;opacity:1; }
        100%{width:0;opacity:1; }
}
```